# groovysh: how to solve "no jansi in java.library.path" in Mac M1?

Tags: groovy, groovysh

I am running `groovysh` (groovy 4.0.8 which is installed by `sdkman`) on my Mac M1, and it raises a warning:

> ansi will be disabled because an error occurred while installing ansi: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path: .... tried: '/private/var/folders/ck/2qcbfbs56075y7vsv6_yg6sr0000gn/T/libjansi-64-7439658586757684124.jnilib' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,i386', need 'arm64')

It seems that it downloads a non-arm64 library. How to solve it?

---

Update: I find that it works if I specify `jansi-2.4.0.jar` in the classpath:

```bash
groovysh -cp /Users/xxx/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/4.0.8/lib/jansi-2.4.0.jar
```

It seems that `groovysh`'s classpath does not contain the packages in `lib`.

I conducted the same installation steps on my Manjaro, and `groovysh` alone works well without specifying the `jansi-2.4.0.jar`. So, what did I miss on Mac M1? Is it a bug of groovysh or jansi?

Answer (score 1):

To enable ANSI color support in Groovy's groovysh on a Mac with ARM architecture, you have to add `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:~/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib/jansi-x.x.x.jar` to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` (depending on your shell). Once you have done editing the file run `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the change.